# How to select identical UV island at one time?

Tags: uv

[image]

I have many similar uv island as in picture, I just want to select those hook-like ones, they have same vertice count, how?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find Blender's default UV tools rather sad and lacking, especially coming from Modo. However, if you have $20 to spare, UV Toolkit (https://blendermarket.com/products/uv-toolkit) gets you pretty close to most major apps. It also has "select similar islands," which is exactly what you are looking for.

[image: UV Toolkit]

Comment: I agree with you , thanks for the advice (at last I had to get UVpackmaster to achieve my desired result , just needed to have all the uvs packed tightly)